# How do I insert random characters into a sql database column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to populate a column of my database table with 253 lines of 'M' and 'F' randomly placed in the column, is this possible?

Example of what it may look like:

```
Gender:
M
M
F
M
F
F
M
F
M
```

Comment: Which _RDBMS_ are you targeting?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For MS SQL you can use [NEWID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newid-transact-sql) and [CHECKSUM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/checksum-transact-sql) functions like:

```
  UPDATE Users 
  SET Gender = (CASE WHEN ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 2) = 1 THEN 'M' ELSE 'F' END)
```

- NEWID() will generate random GUID
- CHECKSUM() will generate hash of that GUID
- ABS() to make it either 1 or 0

---

WARNING! While some people suggesting to use [RAND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rand-transact-sql) function - **please do not use it** for this particular case. The query like this:

```
UPDATE Users SET Gender = CASE WHEN (RAND() > 0.5) THEN 'M' ELSE 'F' END
```

.. will result that you have all values either M or either F.

Potentially you can seed [RAND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rand-transact-sql) function with some value like Id, but distribution of values will be not very good: like first 30-40% all M, then 30-40% all F, then M again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this so you can decrease "0.5" to improve the chances of being picked if you want the "M" to be more dominant.

```
 SELECT CASE WHEN (RAND() > 0.5) THEN 'M' ELSE 'F' END
```

Comment: If you are updating a table using RAND() - its value will be always the same. So you will have whole column of M or F

Comment: Consider this update:  UPDATE Users SET Gender = CASE WHEN (RAND() > 0.5) THEN 'M' ELSE 'F' END

Comment: I guess it depends on the update. This will work for a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RAND()function.

Please read the following URL:
[enter link description here][1]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rand-transact-sql